# Verifying Xcode beta 6.2 occurs every time it launches

Tags: xcode

I've just downloaded Xcode beta 6.2 however every time, e-v-e-r-y time, I launch it OS X is verifying it which is takes several minutes.

Did anybody else have the same problem and knows how to stop it from happening all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in a terminal window:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/Xcode.app
```

That should prevent OS X from having to verify it.

See http://furbo.org/2014/09/03/xcode-vs-gatekeeper/

Comment: I agree that it's not a good idea to work around Gatekeeper and to let it do the verification the first time you run the app after downloading it. The OP was having issues where Gatekeeper was stuck and not clearing the flag after the verification and so it verified every time. In which case, the command above can be used to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. Each time I would launch Xcode, Gatekeeper would kick in and verify the package.

I solved the problem by going to the app store and installing Xcode.